# Django REST Framework: Per-user throttles

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, throttling

I have users that need really high throttles so they can use the system a lot. Is there an easy way to give them higher throttles than the rest of the users?

I've looked around but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 18):

I figured out a way to do this by extending the UserRateThrottle and adding special users to my settings file.

This class just overrides the `allow_request` method, adding some special logic to see if usernames are listed in the `OVERRIDE_THROTTLE_RATES` variable:

```
class ExceptionalUserRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        """
        Give special access to a few special accounts.

        Mirrors code in super class with minor tweaks.
        """
        if self.rate is None:
            return True

        self.key = self.get_cache_key(request, view)
        if self.key is None:
            return True

        self.history = self.cache.get(self.key, [])
        self.now = self.timer()

        # Adjust if user has special privileges.
        override_rate = settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['OVERRIDE_THROTTLE_RATES'].get(
            request.user.username,
            None,
        )
        if override_rate is not None:
            self.num_requests, self.duration = self.parse_rate(override_rate)

        # Drop any requests from the history which have now passed the
        # throttle duration
        while self.history and self.history[-1] <= self.now - self.duration:
            self.history.pop()
        if len(self.history) >= self.num_requests:
            return self.throttle_failure()
        return self.throttle_success()
```

To use this, just set your `DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASS` to this class, then put some special users into `OVERRIDE_THROTTLE_RATES` like so:

```
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
    'cl.api.utils.ExceptionalUserRateThrottle',
),
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
    'anon': '100/day',
    'user': '1000/hour',
},
'OVERRIDE_THROTTLE_RATES': {
    'scout': '10000/hour',
    'scout_test': '10000/hour',
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This idea is really neat and definitely something to include in DRF

Comment: I haven't tried to push this upstream, but I'd be delighted if somebody tried to get it into the main code base.

Comment: For me the ideal solution should be grouping users by groups in the django admin page and throttling by those groups. Trying to do an hybrid between your code and this idea. If I figure out something will post it here

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution after customized Django REST Throttling,

Its Blocking particular user after 3 login attempts (Block user_id that presents in my application). Block IP address after 6 login attempts for anonymous user.

**prevent.py :-**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import Counter

from rest_framework.throttling import SimpleRateThrottle
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserLoginRateThrottle(SimpleRateThrottle):
    scope = 'loginAttempts'

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        user = User.objects.filter(username=request.data.get('username'))
        ident = user[0].pk if user else self.get_ident(request)

        return self.cache_format % {
            'scope': self.scope,
            'ident': ident
        }

    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        """
        Implement the check to see if the request should be throttled.
        On success calls `throttle_success`.
        On failure calls `throttle_failure`.
        """
        if self.rate is None:
            return True

        self.key = self.get_cache_key(request, view)
        if self.key is None:
            return True

        self.history = self.cache.get(self.key, [])
        self.now = self.timer()

        while self.history and self.history[-1] <= self.now - self.duration:
            self.history.pop()

        if len(self.history) >= self.num_requests:
            return self.throttle_failure()

        if len(self.history) >= 3:
            data = Counter(self.history)
            for key, value in data.items():
                if value == 2:
                    return self.throttle_failure()
        return self.throttle_success(request)

    def throttle_success(self, request):
        """
        Inserts the current request's timestamp along with the key
        into the cache.
        """
        user = User.objects.filter(username=request.data.get('username'))
        if user:
            self.history.insert(0, user[0].id)
        self.history.insert(0, self.now)
        self.cache.set(self.key, self.history, self.duration)
        return True
```

**Views.py :-**

```
from .prevent import UserLoginRateThrottle
   ....
   ....
   ....
   class ObtainAuthToken(auth_views.ObtainAuthToken):
       throttle_classes = (UserLoginRateThrottle,)/use this method here your login view

       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           ....
           ....
```

**Settings.py :-**

## Django-rest-framework

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'loginAttempts': '6/hr',
        'user': '1000/min',
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in throttle_success!?
if user:
            self.history.insert(0, user[0].id)
user.id and time are two different properties, right?

Comment: How is this answering the question? The user was asking about how to increase access for specific users, not how to block users who failed login auth

Answer (score 1):

I know this a pretty old thread and the accepted answer was helpful for me as well. I wanted to show how you can have multiple user rate throttles in place, in this case additional ones for the root users

```
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

class RootRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    """
    Limits the rate of API calls that may be made by a given user.
    The user id will be used as a unique cache key if the user is
    authenticated.  For anonymous requests, the IP address of the request will
    be used.
    """

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            ident = request.user.pk
        else:
            ident = self.get_ident(request)

        self.rate = self.get_rate(request)
        logger.debug(
            "Throttling rate for %s: %s", request.user, self.rate
        )

        self.num_requests, self.duration = self.parse_rate(self.rate)
        return self.cache_format % {
            'scope': self.scope,
            'ident': ident
        }

    def get_rate(self, request=None):
        """
        Determine the string representation of the allowed request rate.
        """
        if not getattr(self, 'scope', None):
            msg = ("You must set either `.scope` or `.rate` for '%s' throttle" %
                   self.__class__.__name__)
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg)

        if request and request.user.is_superuser:
            throttle_rates = settings.REST_FRAMEWORK["ROOT_THROTTLE_RATES"]
        else:
            throttle_rates = api_settings.DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES
        try:
            return throttle_rates[self.scope]
        except KeyError:
            msg = "No default throttle rate set for '%s' scope" % self.scope
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg)

class ByMinuteRateThrottle(RootRateThrottle):
    scope = 'minute'


class ByHourRateThrottle(RootRateThrottle):
    scope = 'hour'


class ByDayRateThrottle(RootRateThrottle):
    scope = 'day'
```

the settings part then looks like this

```
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
    'threedi_api.throttling.ByMinuteRateThrottle',
    'threedi_api.throttling.ByHourRateThrottle',
    'threedi_api.throttling.ByDayRateThrottle',
],
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
    'minute': '100/min',
    'hour': '1000/hour',
    'day': '5000/day',
},
'ROOT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
    'minute': '200/min',
    'hour': '2000/hour',
    'day': '10000/day',
},
```

Comment: This seems useful, but where do you put the code?